# a start job is running for dev-disk-by

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I've seen several threads here regarding this problem but still don't know how to fix it hope you can forgive my ignorance and I afraid I might do something I cannot recover.

Here is what my current `/etc/fstab` looks like

I'm running a triple boot OSX, Ubuntu, Kali.

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=fd2a63aa-1510-455d-87ec-a8812fe14431 /  ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=67E3-17ED  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077                     0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=bd1374a9-2be9-4765-818c-a1aedb2bc37c none     swap    sw          0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=4bd96922-1b25-47c0-a94e-5271c11f4caf none     swap    sw          0       0
```

I have two swap partitions one for Ubuntu and another for Kali, after I installed Kali my swap for Ubuntu is no longer being recognized I think and I started getting the "a start up job is running for

Here is how my partitions looks at Gparted in Ubuntu:

```
/dev/sda1 /boot/efi
/dev/sda2 osx
/dev/sda3 recovery
/dev/sda4 recovery
/dev/sda5 linux-swap
/dev/sda6 boot, esp
/dev/sda7 Kali
/dev/sda8 boot, esp
/dev/sda9 linux-swap
/dev/sda10 Ubuntu      /
```

Hope someone could help me and tell me what and how to modify in fstab to make the slow boot error disappear.

Here below is my `lsblk -f` output as suggested.

```
NAME    FSTYPE  LABEL       UUID                               MOUNTPOINT
sda
├─sda1  vfat    EFI         67E3-17ED                                /boot/efi
├─sda2  hfsplus main        d5d30c17-24c4-3c3c-875d-82b607879223 
├─sda3  hfsplus Recovery HD cca7a597-d324-384f-b7e3-a11bfa78a97d 
├─sda4  hfsplus Recovery HD dff89f02-5fdf-35b1-9203-1ed39aa9450b 
├─sda5  swap                e4fc406c-9a49-4460-b261-b5150602ca63      [SWAP]
├─sda6  vfat                3DC7-7316                            
├─sda7  ext4    e3          c65718ca-ce64-4842-ae83-db9c63ed0832 
├─sda8  vfat                74EF-3424                            
├─sda9  swap                4bd96922-1b25-47c0-a94e-5271c11f4caf      [SWAP]
└─sda10 ext4                fd2a63aa-1510-455d-87ec-a8812fe14431       /
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `lsblk -f`. That will contain the UUIDs of your partitions, which is what's used to identify them in your `/etc/fstab`. Leave me a comment "@ByteCommander" when you're done so that I can check it out. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @ByteCommander  I think my sda5 swap is being used by sda7 which is Kali. sda9 should be free but for some reason it is not being recognized.

Answer (score 1):

@ByteCommander thanks forgetting me know about the lsblk -f command, it allowed me to check the proper UUID.
I was able to solve it I simply deleted the first swap on the /etc/fstab I think Ubuntu was getting confused in having 2 swap partitions and it worked, boot up now takes only a few second the "start up job..." is now gone, thanks.